Need chromadb & transformers together but have conflicting requirements as chromadb requires 0.20 version of tokenizers & the later requires 0.21
I have to use chromadb and transformers together for a project but chromadb requires <=0.20.3 version of tokenizers and transformers require >=0.21 version of tokenizers, and the older versions of transformers compatible with chromadb need rust compilers, so that is not an option either.
I tried upgrading transformers, tokenizers and also downgrading the transformers but nothing working and for all of this I am using a virtual environment.

FYI https://github.com/chroma-core/chroma/issues/3265

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

pip install transformers==4.46.0 tokenizers==0.20.3

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
